# How to enable TCP/IP for Postgres on OS X 10.7 Server?

Tags: osx-server, server.app, postgresql

The default configuration in `/var/pgsql/postgresql.conf` says that `listen_addresses` defaults to `localhost`, but it doesn't let me connect over port 5432.  Connecting (as root, using sudo) over a Unix domain socket works fine, but I need to enable network connections.

I tried uncommenting the `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` line (to make it explicit), and restarting the Postgres process (with `sudo serveradmin stop postgres`, `sudo serveradmin start postgres`), but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postgres process started by "serveradmin" has command-line arguments added by `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`.  The default includes `-c listen_addresses=`, which turns off TCP/IP.

Changing it to `listen_addresses=localhost`, and restarting Postgres, solved the problem.  (I suppose I could probably also remove the `-c` argument entirely.)

(One comment I found somewhere suggested that in 10.8 Server, the file you need to edit is `/Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Config/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`, but I haven't upgraded to 10.8 yet so I can't confirm this.)